# T_SQL counting particular values in one row with multiple columns

Tags: t-sql

I have little problem with counting cells with particular value in one row in MSSMS.
Table looks like

| ID | Month | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | ... | 31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 1 | null | null | 1 | 1 | null | 1 | 1 | null | null | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | null | null | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | null | ... | 1 |

I need to count how many cells in one row have value for example 1.  In this case it would be 5.
Data represents worker shifts in a month. Be aware that there is a column named month (FK with values 1-12), i don't want to count that in a result.
Column ID is ALWAYS 4 digit number.

Possibility is to use count(case when) but in examples there are only two or three columns not 31. Statement will be very long. Is there any other option to count it?

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server#15745076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to strongly suggest that you abandon your current table design, and instead store one day per month, per *record*, not column.  That is, use this design:

```
ID   | Date       | Value
5000 | 2021-01-01 | NULL
5000 | 2021-01-02 | NULL
5000 | 2021-01-03 | 1
5000 | 2021-01-04 | 1
5000 | 2021-01-05 | NULL
...
5000 | 2021-01-31 | 5
```

Then use this query:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    CONVERT(varchar(7), Date, 120),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = 1 THEN 1 END) AS one_cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID,
    CONVERT(varchar(7), Date, 120);
```

Comment: Thanks, tables are rebuilded and it looks like its suites to other part of DB.